# SQL Server 2008 R2 is it free for local db?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to set up database for my desktop application, for this I want to use SQL Server 2008 R2

Can you please tell me is it free or I need to purchase.

Comment: Just download the express editions since they are free. [Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express - powerful and reliable **free** data management system that delivers a rich and reliable data store for lightweight Web Sites and desktop applications.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Comment: Thx for replay. i faced some problem in 2012 like abnormal jumping for auto generation columns. that's why i need to move sql2008. can u please suggest.

Comment: maybe this will help you [Odd SQL Server 2012 IDENTITY issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657461/odd-sql-server-2012-identity-issue)

Answer (score 2):

Just download the **express editions** since they are **free**.

[Microsoft® SQL Server® 2012 Express - powerful and reliable free data management system that delivers a rich and reliable data store for lightweight Web Sites and desktop applications.](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29062)

Although SQL Server 2012 Express has limitation.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There is a free version, sqlexpress, which is free not because you run it on your desktop, but because of the memory and database size limitations. You can run it on your desktop, or on a server and it will still be free;  if your needs ever grow such that you need a bigger database, more cpu's or more memory, the upgrade is painless (except to your wallet)..

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx

Comment: thx for replay, can i access this db from another local systems?

Comment: yes, as long as your firewall allows the access to the port (usually 1433, but not always).