# SQL server 2008 enterprise RESEED to 0 anormally

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework

I am using EF 5.0, and sometimes no one can register on server by same error, PK PK_Invalid, and the PK is AUTO INCREMENT, this jumped 1000 to 10000 sometimes, but now this reseting to 0 and try subscribe a exists id. Why? How prevent?

**NOTE**

To fix I am using DBCC CHECKIDENT (User, reseed, 1080002).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Odd SQL Server 2012 IDENTITY issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657461/odd-sql-server-2012-identity-issue)

Comment: If I have one big int, I dont care if the IDENTITY jump some numbers, but no one saying about the IDENTITY stop count or go to old values, and server will keep insert old ids whit complety fail.